# Use 2 different Storyboards, one for LTR and one for RTL (NOT AUTO LAYOUT)

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

My app now support **RTL** languages, i want to add support for **LTR** languages.
i created additional `storyboard` file and set the alignment(of all the labels, buttons, pics etc..) to support **LTR**.

Now, how can i know that the user using **LTR** language and how should i tell the app to use the **LTR** storyboard?

i tried to use auto layout - without success.

so i decided to do it that way, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard;

  // Determine the text direction and load the Storyboard accordingly
  if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RTL" bundle:nil];
  } else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LTR" bundle:nil];
  }

  // Get the initial view controller
  UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialViewController"];

  self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```